# How to see that the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor satisfies the null energy condition?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to show that the Maxwell stress-energy tensor,
$$T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\left( F_{\mu\rho} F^{\rho}{}_{\nu} - \frac{1}{4}\eta_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho \sigma} F^{\rho\sigma} \right),$$
satisfies the null energy condition, i.e., that
$$T_{\mu \nu}k^\mu k^\nu \geq 0$$
for all null vectors $k^\mu$. I see that the second term vanishes on contraction with $k^\mu k^\nu$, but I'm struggling to see how to manipulate the first term.

Comment: It is very important to to write $F_{\;\;\nu}^\rho$ in the first term. Since the electromagnetic tensor is antisymmetric, the expression is different from $F_\nu^{\;\;\rho}$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that what you are trying to show is that $k^\mu F_{\mu}{}^\nu$ is a spacelike vector (in this answer, I'm assuming the $-+++$ metric convention). Hence, let us focus on this particular vector.

Given $k^\mu$ at some point, pick a choice of Cartesian coordinates such that $k^\mu = (1,1,0,0)^\intercal$, which is always possible. In this choice of coordinates, the field strength tensor reads (units with $c=1$)
$$F_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -E_1 & -E_2 & -E_3 \\ E_1 & 0 & B_3 & -B_2 \\ E_2 & -B_3 & 0 & B_1 \\ E_3 & B_2 & -B_1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Notice then that
$$k^\mu F_{\mu}{}^{\nu} = \begin{pmatrix} -E_1 \\ -E_1 \\ -E_2 + B_3 \\ -E_3 - B_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

A straighforward computation then shows that $k^\mu F_{\mu}{}^{\nu} k^\rho F_{\rho}{}_{\nu}$ is the sum of two explicitly non-negative terms.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the product

\begin{equation}
F^{ab}k_a k_b
\end{equation}

where I have used latin indices to indicate that the result is basis independent. Now since $F_{ab}$ is anti-symmetric; this product will be $0$. Writing this result in a slightly different way we have

\begin{equation}
V \cdot k = 0
\end{equation}

where  $V^a = F^{ab}k_b$. Since $k$ is a null vector you can show that because of this result; $V$ is either null or space-like. Therefore; we have

\begin{equation}
T^{ab} k_a k_b = \frac{1}{4\pi}\left( F^{ac}k_cF_{ab}k^b \right) = \frac{1}{4\pi}(V \cdot V) 
\end{equation}

which is bigger or equal to zero because $V$ is either space-like or null.

$\textbf{Edit}$:
To show that a vector $X$ is spacelike or null if $X \cdot Y = 0$ for any null vector $Y$, go to a coordinate system at an arbitrary point $p$ where the metric is $g = diag(-1,1,1,1)$ and $Y = (1,1,0,0)$ at p. Then the inner product directly implies the desired result. Note further that this coordinate system always exists as one can perform many Lorentz transformations for put the vector $Y$ in the desired form which leaves the metric invariant at that point $p.$

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided by Nickolas Alves should suffice, here is an alternate proof of NEC satisfied by free Electromagnetic field using the idea of 2-spinor formalism (and hence, this proof is very particular to 3+1 dim space-time, see [1] )

The idea is that a real null vector $k^a$ can be written as tensor product of two 2-spinors, one being the conjugate of other:

$k^a\leftrightarrow k^A\bar{k}^{A'}$

where $k^A$ is defined upto an overall phase factor. Note that $k^ak_a\leftrightarrow k^Ak_A\bar{k}^{A'}\bar{k}_{A'}=0$ which follows form the fact that $k^Ak_A=\epsilon_{AB}k^Ak^B= \epsilon_{[AB]}k^Ak^B=0$

The Maxwell tensor $F_{ab}$ in this formalism can be written in terms of a symmetric 2-spinors $\phi_{AB}$ as follows:
$F_{ab}\leftrightarrow \phi_{AB}\epsilon_{A'B'}+c.c.$

It turns out that the stress energy tensor $T_{ab}$ of the EM field can be simply written as (see chapter 3 & 5 from [1])

$T_{ab}\leftrightarrow\phi_{AB}\bar{\phi}_{A'B'}$

The Null energy condition follows naturally: $T_{ab}k^ak^b\leftrightarrow |\phi_{AB}k^Ak^B|^2\geq 0$

[1] R. Penrose, W. Rindler, "Spinors and Space-Time. Volume-I: Two-Spinor Calculus and Relativistic Fields", Cambridge University Press (1984)

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $$k^\mu k^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho \sigma} F^{\rho\sigma}  = k_\mu k^\mu F_{\rho \sigma} F^{\rho\sigma} = 0 \,.$$

Then notice that $$ k^\mu F_{\mu\rho} k^\nu F^{\rho}{}_{\nu} $$ is of the form $a_\rho a^\rho >0$* if $a$a is spacelike.

*$F$ is assumed to be real valued. The proof for complex $F$ is very similar.

Note that as this holds for arbitrary spacelike $F^{\mu\nu}$, the relation to electromagnetism is unclear.

Comment: For this argument to work, the vector $a^\rho = k^\nu F^\rho {}_\nu$ has to be spacelike (or at least not timelike).  That's where the specific properties of the electromagnetic tensor $F^{\mu \nu}$ come in.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Indeed, $a$ should be spacelike. I corrected my answer.

Still, how does that imply a link with electromagnetism?

Comment: See [Nicolas Alves's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/711110/81133) for an explanation / justification.  It appears to have something to do with the antisymmetry of $F^{\mu \nu}$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Alves argues correctly that the EM field tensor gives a spacelike vector but any tensor with this property will do.